# Is there a way to find and select a 2nd variable range via VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Hi have a report that is generated automatically and I want to create a macro that formats the report into something I can use as a database on our network drive. The report generates 2 tables that I want to streamline into 1 table. How do I find the range of the 2nd table when the 2nd table is never in exactly the same place due to the number of rows in each table changing daily.
If it helps, there is a unique header in the second table named "Potential Locations" which is the last row of the 2nd table.

I'm not really sure where to start with this code.

I basically want to run the macro to find the 2nd table and select it, delete the headers then move it 2 rows up and 2 columns to the right.

Comment: Use `Range.Find` maybe? Do you have any code so far?

Comment: No, sorry, I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: You could start with the macro recorder. Maybe record finding "Potential Locations," then delete the headers, then move. That should get you pretty far, and we can help with the rest.

Comment: That was the first thing I did but since the tables can be of varying sizes it isn't really helping.

Comment: I would have thought the answer was with 'CurrentRegion.Select"? I just don't know how to let that function know what cell it needs to search from.

Comment: This would be so much easier with Power Query than with VBA. Look at https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2d358dde-b337-42e4-a0eb-57349c276e3d/remove-top-n-rows-where-n-is-dynamic?forum=powerquery

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, I got there in the end, see code below for how I resolved my issue.

```
Sub FORMAT_CUSTOMER_ORDER_REPORT()
'
' FORMAT_CUSTOMER_ORDER_REPORT Macro
' RE-ORGANISES CUSTOMER ORDER CLEANUP REPORT AND SAVES TO SHARED DRIVE IN FORRECT FILE FORMAT
'

    'Code below adjusts column widths and deleted first row

    Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 5.14
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 10
    Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 10.86
    Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 4.14
    Columns("G:G").ColumnWidth = 43.43
    Columns("H:H").ColumnWidth = 5.14
    Columns("I:I").ColumnWidth = 3.43


    'Deletes top row.

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp


    'Code below finds and selects the cell with "POTENTIAL" in it.

    Cells.Find(What:="POTENTIAL", _
               After:=ActiveCell, _
               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, _
               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, _
               SearchFormat:=False).Activate


    'Code below 'cuts' the 'current region'.
        ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cut


    'Code below pastes clipboard to the first blank cell in Column C.
        Range("C1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste


    'Code below selects "current region" which in this case is the entire sheet
        ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select

    'Code below finds and selects the cell with "POTENTIAL" in it.
        Cells.Find(What:="POTENTIAL", _
          After:=ActiveCell, _
          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
          LookAt:=xlPart, _
          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
          MatchCase:=False, _
          SearchFormat:=False).Activate

    'Code below select entire row of currently selected cell.
        ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

    'Deletes selection
        Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp

    'Selects 'current region'.
        ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Select

        'Code below freezes first row
        Rows("1:1").Select
    With ActiveWindow
        .SplitColumn = 0
        .SplitRow = 1
    End With
    ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    Cells.Select
    Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("B1:B2931"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With Sheet1.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:N10000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-6


    'Code below Sorts entire sheet by Column B, A - Z.
        Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheet1.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:= _
        Range("B1:B10000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With Sheet1.Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:N10000")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With


    'Code Below Saves File to network shared drive with the correct name
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "R:\6024 Onsite\ONSITE CUSTOMER ORDERS\6024 CUSTOMER REPORT.xlsx", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False


End Sub
```